# How Can I Get Client Windows Identity from Published Web Site on IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, single-sign-on, windows-identity

Server and Client in the same Domain. I am trying to get client windows identity from Published Web Site on IIS.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string userNameWithDomain = identity.Name.ToString();
string identityName = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

**By the Way, I dont want to type username and password to anywhere...**

I am already tried below parts and parts combinations but still the web page requires username and password

[image]

- Windows Authentication

[image]

if iispool(autotest) is default and windows authentication is enabled result is

```
userNameWithDomain = "FALAN\Filan"// Server Identity name
identityName = "IIS APPPOOL\autotest"// IIS Pool
userName  = "FALAN\Bilgehan" // After I typed the username and password, this variable gives me the correct answer. However as you can see up, i dont want to type username and password to anywhere
```

- IIS Pool

I enter custom account information for iispool

[image]

```
userNameWithDomain = "FALAN\Filan"// Server Identity name
identityName = "FALAN\Filan"// Server Identity name
userName  = "FALAN\Bilgehan" // After I typed the username and password, this variable gives me the correct answer. However as you can see up, i dont want to type username and password to anywhere
```

- Web Config

I did `identity impersonate="true"`

and

I did `authentication mode="Windows"`

- Visual Studio

[image]

As you can see I couldnt catch correct answer. How Can I Get Client Windows Identity from Published Web Site on IIS without enter username and password?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried using the User in the HttpContext?